# ActiveRecord polymorphic has_many with ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I have the following Concern:

```
module Eventable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  # ...
  included do
    has_many :subscriptions, as: :entity, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

My Models are:

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Eventable
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my controller I try to create a subscription for an experiment, as following:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_entity

  def create
    subscription = Subscriptions.new(params[:subscription])
    @entity.subscriptions << subscription # Why is it false?
    # ...
  end

end
```

**But it doesn't work.**

While debugging, I noticed that 
`@entity.subscriptions.count` create incorrect SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [subscriptions] WHERE [subscriptions].[experiment_id] = 123
```

while I expect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [subscriptions] WHERE [subscriptions].[entity_id] = 123 AND [subscriptions].[entity_type] = 'Experiment'
```

**Note:** If I do the following, it works correctly:

```
subscription.entity = @entity
subscription.save
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: the sql query indicating the polymorphic association failed, but the `subscription.entity = @entity` worked, it seems a conflicting result to me.  **Is that possible that when creating the new subscription there are some important attribute missing** that makes `@entity.subscriptions << subsciption failed?`

Answer (score 0):

The  reason for this error: `class Experiment` (not my class) already had `has_many :subscriptions`

**Advise:** if you have strange behavior, and you use others people code, stop and review the code!